# PayZone payment gateway magento Error

Tags: magento, payment, gateway

Integrated PayZone Payment gateway with magento using their magento module on a hosted payment platform. (redirect to payment provider then back to website)

Getting the below error after card details entered

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage::saveOrderAfterRedirectedPaymentAction() in /home/magentowebsite/public_html/app/code/local/Payzone/Tpg/controllers/PaymentController.php on line 499
```

Any ideas on how what may be causing this issue?

Comment: Well, there's a function it's trying to call that doesn't exist. What version of Magento are you using, and what versions does the plugin support?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?